# Native vlan on D-link switches

Tags: switch, vlan, switching, trunk

I need to configure the trunk ports of the switch to tag all untagged frames with native VID.Configuring native vlan "Cisco way" is a solution. So I am looking for a way to configure native vlan on trunk ports of D-link DGS-3100 switches?

Comment: Unfortunately, D-Link doesn't offer optional, paid support for its products, which is a requirement to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with D-Link Switches (actually the research I made to answer you question confort me in my postion to never ever buy those stuff for any serious network...) but from the documentation (found [here](http://www.dlink.com/uk/en/support/product/dgs-3100-series-managed-l2-stackable-gigabit-switches)) , you should be able to set several vlan as tagged for a specific port and another one as untagged.

- you create VLAN 10 and set it as tagged for port 4
- you create VLAN 20 and set it as tagged for port 4
- you create VLAN 30 and sit it as untagged for port 4

In command line :

> create vlan VLAN_10 tag 10
>     create vlan VLAN_20 tag 20
>     create vlan VLAN_30 tag 30
>
> config vlan vlanid 10 add tagged 4
>     config vlan vlanid 20 add tagged 4
>     config vlan vlanid 30 add untagged 4

In this configuration the port 4 will behave as a trunk port with native VLAN 30.

Note that it's unclear if the port PVID will be set correctly with this configuration, there's PVID configuration command only within GVRP, so ???

Also note that D-Link use the term `trunk` for both Link Aggregation and VLAN trunking which could be confusing.

Comment: What if I want VLAN 10(your example) to be "both tagged and untagged" on port 4.
So if port 4 of SW1 receives encapsulated frames(VLAN 10) it is ok,else if it receives Ethernet frames it tags them as VLAN 10.

Comment: In my example it is VLAN 30 which is untagged, so you can't received frame for VLAN 10 as untagged. Receiving both tagged and untagged frames for the same vlan should work but you have to test it, we cannot guess how DLINK choosed to implement it. Egressing frames will always be untagged tough.  Anyway, you should NOT be receiving both tagged and untagged frames for the same vlan on a port, this is a bad design.